# validating address using javascript

Tags: java, javascript, servlets

I want to validate address using javascript.
1.We can't enter special symbols.
2.We can enter numbers, alphabets.
3.We can enter some special characters ,-/

I wrote the code like this but this is not fulfilling my requirement.

```
if(address.value == "") {
    window.alert("Error: Address must not be null.");
    address.focus();
    return false;
}

re = /^\w+$,/
if(!re.test(address.value)) {
    window.alert("Error: Address must contain only letters, numbers and underscores.");
    address.focus();
    return false;
}
```

Please help me.
Thank You.

Comment: what do you mean of `We can't enter special symbols` and `We can enter some special characters ,-/` i think both are same. so how you can restrict them

Comment: I don't want these special symbols !@#$%^&*(){}[]?|~                     I want these special symbols ,.-/ that means i want only specific special symbols. Is that possible?   Thank you for your response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you also want to allow whitespaces in an address try:

```
re = /^[A-z0-9\s\.,/-]+$/
```

If there can be only one word:

```
re = /^[A-z0-9\.,/-]+$/
```